# is The Timer Updated Correctly and pricisely?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am new to Javafx, and i am trying to create a Timer.
I have created a simple button and label.
on clicking the button, `startTimer` event is notified and the label will start showing the counter

Will the Timer be Precise?

And will it be better to use Create the task and TimerTask in the Event Function or is this one good too?

Controller.java -

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.util.Timer;

import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Controller {

    @FXML

    private Label timerLabel;

    int secondsPassed = 0;

    Timer timer;

    TimerTask timerTask;
    public void initialize() {
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        secondsPassed++;
                       timerLabel.setText(String.valueOf(secondsPassed));
                    }
                });
            }
        };

    }

    public void startTimer() {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml-

```
<Button text="Start" onAction="#startTimer" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>

<Label fx:id="timerLabel" text="0" alignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" style="-fx-text-alignment: center" prefWidth="50"/>
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: As the timer does not offer real time guarantees, you may be better off calculating the time using Instant.now() to record the start time, then getting a new instant on each invocation of the timer task and calculating the difference between them using [duration or period apis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html).  Alternatively to a timer task, you could use a Timeline and call getCurrentTime in a key frame.

Comment: On "Create the task and TimerTask in the Event Function or is this one good too", it depends upon what you are doing.  If you want a global timer, then just create one instance.  If you want to create many timers, a new one each time an event is triggered, each with different timing scheduling, then create a new one each time in the event function.

Comment: I think so that the difference between successive countera might not be constant as program.runLater might take some time?